# Django app do not render html templates (no requirements.txt)

Tags: python, django

I am working with this app, I have tried running the app using the command provided in the doc then I had to install both `Django` and `requests` but now the template view do not render at all, it seems it's interpreted as text

[image: screenshot]

What do I have to install? Or this app is not working properly? I am not sure why there's no requirements.txt

Below is the `settings` file

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxx'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Company.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

There's also a file named `urls.py` that contains the path I am supposed to work with

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^payment_request/',Payment_Request),
    url(r'^payment_response/',Payment_Response),
    url(r'^payment_receipt/',Payment_Receipt),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Only admin is working, `Payment_Receipt` and `Payment_Response` shows error but that's normal because they should get some data to process before

I also I'd like to mention that in the docs they ask to generate some hash sequence, is that mandatory to simply shows the htm template? I have never done this before

> Create SHA256 Hash with below mention Parameters.
> Merchant needs to form the below hash sequence before posting the transaction.
>
> Below is the SHA 256 Hash creation format : Hash Sequence :-
> `trackid|Terminalid|password|secret_key|amount|currency_code`

Comment: have you typed the link manually or have you clicked on a link on the index page?

Comment: @Sven It's the same thing bro, I have tried another path and it's working

Comment: Could you post your settings.py WITHOUT THE SECRET KEY OF COURSE

Comment: Maybe you just need to put the app in the installed apps in settings.py

Comment: @Sven I have updated the question and added settings.py, when I go to /admin it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways this could happen:

1. Content type is wrong - Open up the Chrome Developer Console, Go to Network tab, reload the page and look at the content-type header in the request. Is it text/html? If it's something else, Chrome won't render it
2. The HTML is escaped - Right click on the page and click View Source. Is it different from the HTML you see in the page?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the name of the app in settings.py in the list INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "appname",
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: Thanks I have updated the question, I am pretty I don't have to edit any code or install anything, this production-ready API from a payment processor

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but I would still recommend to install the app in settings.py